# Query Business Units in Marketing cloud

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to get all BU for marketing cloud. but not able to do. The objective to get all BU present in the system . below is the soap request and response,

```html
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
     <wsa:Action>Retrieve</wsa:Action>
     <wsa:To>{{SOAPBaseURI}}/Service.asmx</wsa:To>
  <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{token}}</fueloauth>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
             <Options>
              <Client>
               <ID>{{AccountMID}}</ID>
              </Client>
             </Options>
                <ObjectType>BusinessUnit</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The above is soap body

I am getting following error :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <title>Error</title>
 <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" />
 <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="C#" />
 <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript" />
 <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Arial;">
 <table style="height:100%; width:100%;" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr style="height:10%; background-color:#808080">
   <td>
    <div style="color:#ffffff; font-size: 16px;">An error has occurred and has been logged by our system.
     <br />
      Thank you. </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
   <td>
    <div id="errorTxt">&nbsp;</div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

any clues what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I moved away from token to username password logic , plus query all account and able to get data as needed

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>{{Username}}</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>{{Password}}</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>BusinessUnit</ObjectType>
                <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>ParentID</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>                
                <AccountUsers>
                    <AccountUser>
                        <Properties>Email</Properties>
                    </AccountUser>
                </AccountUsers>             
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi did you manage to also retrieve the account users for the business units, i seem to not get them when doing the above soap request?